# Align text left above (relative to) div

Tags: css, flexbox

I have some `h2` text that is currently aligned to the left in the mobile view, above a centered div. How can I instead align it flush left relative to the div in the mobile view (with media query provided in the CSS below applied)?

[image]

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/nataliecardot/pen/MGmvpZ)

Relevant HTML:

```
<section class="container-projects">
        <h2 class="portfolio-header">Featured Work</h2>
        <div class="project">
```

Relevant CSS:

```
    .portfolio-header {
      /* Puts header in its own row without removing from container with row flex direction (setting parent container to wrap also required) */
      width: 100%;
      text-align: left;
      color: #7d97ad;
    }

    .container-projects {
      display: flex;
      /* Parent container needs this for flex-item to take full width in row */
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-between;
      margin: 2em 0;
    }

/* Special styling for screens up to 767px wide, inclusive (applies to landscape phones) */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  header, .container, footer {
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  /* Must specify max-width for img even though parent .container has the same declaration because max-width isn't inherited */
  .container img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  .project {
    /* Centers projects (aligned left otherwise) */
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

}
```

Comment: `in the mobile view` right..?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I added the media query used to the provided CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OZjWwJ?editors=1100

Slightly modified HTML

```html
<section class="portfolio">
  <h2 class="portfolio-header">Featured Work</h2>
  <div class="container-projects">
    <div class="project">
      <img class="project-image" src="https://image.ibb.co/hv4c8n/santorini_small.jpg" alt="View from island of Santorini on a sunny day">
      <h3>Project No. 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="project">
      <img class="project-image" src="https://image.ibb.co/c9sKM7/coast_small.jpg" alt="Distant view of a rugged island with a sailboat nearby">
      <h3>Project No. 2</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="project">
      <img class="project-image" src="https://image.ibb.co/eO9oES/mediterranean_small.jpg" alt="Bird's eye view of a rocky beach with clear turquoise waters">
      <h3>Project No. 3</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

and CSS

```css
.portfolio {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .portfolio {
    width: 90%;
  }
}
```

This way, you are wrapping both your h2 and your project images in one container, which makes it a little more logical to manage their margin on screen. `margin: 0 auto` aligns the container at the center of the screen, which is desirable on all screen widths.

The 992px media query comes from Bootstrap 4's standardized grid system: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options

Answer (score 0):

You can add media query for mobile

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .portfolio-header {
        width: 300px;
        margin: 10px auto;
    }
}
```